# is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given --- Composer --- Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

I want to install druapl modules using Composer
`composer require drupal/swagger_ui_formatter`

but I found this error

```
[ErrorException] is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
```

Even when typing the command "composer update", there is always this error

Drupal version 8.9.1
Php version 7.3.15

Comment: It is likely that somewhere in your code where is_dir is used(maybe a service container class) you are passing an array instead of a string, the best way to find solution to this problem would be to find every ocurrance of is_dir in your core application

Comment: Can you share more context? Is there any stacktrace given?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

**Quick fix**: Run `composer require drupal/swagger_ui_formatter --no-plugins`

**Proper fix**:

My issue was configuring `drupal/core-composer-scaffold` incorrectly.

See [the Drupal.org issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3091285#comment-14374882).

**Before composer.json**

```
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "./",
        "file-mapping": {
            "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": false,
            "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": false
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

**After composer.json**

```
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "./"
      },
      "file-mapping": {
        "[web-root]/sites/default/default.services.yml": false,
        "[web-root]/sites/default/default.settings.php": false
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

**Error Message**

Previously, when running: `composer require drupal/SOME_MODULE -vvv`, I got the error.

```
> post-install-cmd: Drupal\Composer\Plugin\Scaffold\Plugin->postCmd


  [ErrorException]
  is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:180
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
```